# LEFT JOIN 4 tables

Tags: mysql

The totals, indirect, and direct tables and pulling data from "summary".  The last table "int_data" is pulling from "aspect_summary" ... I can't get it to play nice with the rest of them.  My queries are only giving me 1 row of results and I can't figure out why. Suggestions?

```
SELECT user, 
amin,
COALESCE(sum(tavg*tcomp)) AS d_task_min, 
COALESCE(indirect.iminutes,0) AS i_task_min, 
COALESCE(((amin)+(indirect.iminutes)/60),0) AS FAKE_d_call_hour,
COALESCE(tcomp*tavg,0) + COALESCE(indirect.iminutes,0) AS totals,
hrs_earned, 
hrs_equiv, 
minutes, 
diff,
COALESCE(SUM(tot_rec_tasks)-sum(tot_i_tasks),0) AS tot_d_tasks,
COALESCE(tot_i_tasks,0) AS tot_i_tasks,
int_id,

ROUND(COALESCE((((amin-(sum(indirect.iminutes)))/60)+ (sum(indirect.iminutes)/60)),0),2) AS ttime2, 
ROUND(COALESCE((hrs_earned / (((amin-(sum(indirect.iminutes)))/60)+ (sum(indirect.iminutes)/60)))*100,0),2) AS prod, 
ROUND((COALESCE((hrs_earned / hrs_equiv),0)*100),2) AS eff,
ROUND(COALESCE(hrs_earned/(((amin-(sum(indirect.iminutes)))/60)+ (sum(indirect.iminutes)/60)),0)*100,2) AS util,
amin AS aspect_time

FROM
(
SELECT 
U.user_name AS user, 
U.user_id AS tuser_id,
M.minutes AS tminutes, 
ta.task_type AS ttasktype,
ta.task_average as tavg,
tc.completed as tcomp,
ROUND(SUM((((TA.task_average)*TC.completed))/60),2) AS ttime,
ROUND(SUM((((TA.task_average)*TC.completed))/60),2) AS hrs_earned, 
ROUND(SUM(((TA.task_average/6)*TC.completed)),2) AS hrs_equiv,
ROUND(SUM(M.minutes/60),2) AS minutes, 
ROUND((SUM(M.minutes)/60),2)-ROUND(SUM((TA.task_average*TC.completed)/60),2) AS diff,
SUM(TC.completed) AS tot_rec_tasks

    FROM summary S
    JOIN users U 
    ON U.user_id = S.user_id
    JOIN minutes M 
    ON M.minutes_id = S.minutes_id
    JOIN tcompleted TC 
    ON TC.tcompleted_id = S.tcompleted_id
    JOIN tasks TA 
    ON TA.task_id = S.task_id
    JOIN hour_interval H 
    ON H.hourinterval_id = S.hourinterval_id 
    AND DATE(submit_date) = curdate()
    AND TIME(submit_date) BETWEEN '00:00:00' and '23:59:59'
    GROUP BY tuser_id) AS total
LEFT JOIN
    (SELECT U.user_id AS iuser_id, M.minutes AS iminutes, tc.completed AS tot_i_tasks
    FROM summary S
    JOIN users U 
    ON U.user_id = S.user_id
    JOIN minutes M 
    ON M.minutes_id = S.minutes_id
    JOIN tasks TA 
    ON TA.task_id = S.task_id
    JOIN tcompleted TC 
    ON TC.tcompleted_id = S.tcompleted_id
    WHERE TA.task_type='indirect'
    AND DATE(submit_date) = curdate()
    AND TIME(submit_date) BETWEEN '00:00:00' and '23:59:59'
    GROUP BY iuser_id) AS indirect
ON tuser_id = iuser_id
LEFT JOIN
    (SELECT U.user_id AS duser_id
    FROM summary S
    JOIN users U 
    ON U.user_id = S.user_id
    JOIN minutes M 
    ON M.minutes_id = S.minutes_id
    JOIN tcompleted TC 
    ON TC.tcompleted_id = S.tcompleted_id
    JOIN tasks TA 
    ON TA.task_id = S.task_id
    WHERE TA.task_type='direct'
    AND DATE(submit_date) = curdate()
    AND TIME(submit_date) BETWEEN '00:00:00' and '23:59:59'
    GROUP BY duser_id) AS direct
ON tuser_id = duser_id
LEFT JOIN
    (Select U.user_id AS int_id, SUM(M.minutes) AS amin
    FROM aspect_summary A
    JOIN users U ON U.user_id = A.user_id
    JOIN minutes M ON M.minutes_id = A.minutes_id
    JOIN hour_interval H ON H.hourinterval_id = A.hourinterval_id
    AND DATE(submit_date) = curdate()
    AND TIME(submit_date) BETWEEN '00:00:00' and '23:59:59'
    GROUP BY int_id) AS int_data
ON tuser_id = int_id
```

Comment: break down your query to do some individual selects and identify which inner query is giving you the wrong result.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Broke down the queries as nawfal requested and voila... problem solved.  I was adding SUM where it wasnt necessary, which was causing columns to total and causing only 1 row to show.